# How to send spam to personal Junk folder with Exchange 2003 SP2?

Tags: exchange

I am trying to configure an Exchange Server to work with an antispam appliance so that all emails detected as spam by the appliance are sent to the exchange users personal junk folder (if possible without adding any third-party modules to Exchange).

I have read that IMF reads the X-SCL header and sends emails with high SCL values to the junk folder, so I was thinking I could simply add an X-SCL header with the antispam appliance but this does not seem to work. I'm wondering if Exchange doesn't re-classify the message when it is received or something similar.

So I was wondering if it is possible to route emails to the junk folder using an event sink? I have seen ways to send them to the "Badmail" folder but this is not really what is wanted in this case.

Regards

Comment: Any particular reason this is community wiki?

Comment: Fair question Sam. I'm also interested in learning why my answers are listed as being in the wiki, even though I only post in serverfault.

Answer (score 1):

Use of the Junk mail folder has to be enabled per user. You need to go into outlook web access and enable the junk email prevention in the options section, mail classified as junk will then move to the junk mail folder. This needs to be done by each user.

[image: enable spam filter]

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/2006.10.weightlists.aspx?pr=blog

This describes the almost unknown CustomWeightEntry feature in the IMF. Irritatingly it doesn't have the option to check headers, but it can check the subject line so you could have your mail filter add something to the subject line.

It's worth checking that your IMF is actually doing anything. Use PerfMon and check the IMF counters to make sure it is processing mail. It needs enabling in two different places and it's easy to miss one.

JR

Answer (score 1):

I used spam assassin on my server and then just created a rule to check the header to see if the rule the message was flagged as spam.